# DataLabels hide themselves even after allowOverlap is set to true. How to fix it?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

```
HIGHCHARTS
```

Please Have a look at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zxmpy84g/7/). In this Example, the "Opera" dataLabel is hidden even if allowOverlap is set to true. How to fix this? Please share your ideas.

**EDIT:**

Here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zxmpy84g/8/).

Comment: I mean... Opera is less than 3 percent, so it is "hidden" (blank label) on purpose...

Comment: Like @HalvorStrand said look the lines 23 to 26 of the Js code

Comment: I am really sorry Halvor and Core972. I did not notice that line. Here is my update in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxmpy84g/8/). Please have a look at it. Now "opera12" dataLabel is hidden even when allowOverlap property is set to true. Can you help me to figure out why this happen? @HalvorStrand,@Core972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such density, not all labels will display. The solution for that problem is setting `padding` of data labels to 0, increasing `distance` property or simply changing height of chart to higher value.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.padding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/u86cosyg/ - increasing height and setting padding to 0
http://jsfiddle.net/7xLm1xma/ - increasing distance

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Again saved my day. @d_paul